Why does MqlRates seem to update randomly?
I am attempting to map out the Daily Highs of the last 7 days using the code below:
`
#include <Trade\Trade.mqh> // Get code from other places
//#include <scripts\functions.mqh> 
CTrade Trade;

MqlRates DailyOHLC[]; // Declare the arrays at the global scope


int OnInit()
{
    EventSetTimer(172799); //every 2 days - 1 second
    ArraySetAsSeries(DailyOHLC, true);
    return (INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
    //--- 
    EventKillTimer();
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
       
}

void OnTimer() {

   // Copy the latest daily OHLC data into the array
   int DailyPrices = CopyRates(_Symbol, PERIOD_D1, 0, 14, DailyOHLC);
   
   // Check if data was successfully copied
   if (DailyPrices > 0) {
       Print("Successfully copied daily prices. Number of items in DailyOHLC: ", DailyPrices);
       
       // Print the high values of the last 7 daily candles
       Print("Daily OHLC Highs: ", DailyOHLC[0].high, " ", DailyOHLC[1].high, " ",       DailyOHLC[2].high, " ", 
             DailyOHLC[3].high, " ", DailyOHLC[4].high, " ", DailyOHLC[5].high, " ",  DailyOHLC[6].high);
   } else {
       Print("Failed to copy daily prices. Return value: ", DailyPrices);
}
}
   

the problem I am facing is that when I print the daily prices every 2 days or so, I do not find the array to have always changed. what am I doing wrong? is this a data problem? is there a better way?
Journal
I initially set this up to update daily but realised that the "high" of the current candle when set at midnight would just be the opening price, so to combat this I changed the Ontimer function to run every 2 days minus 1 second ( should receive the high of current candle unless current candle high is at close).
